# startx as user on system boot fails

Tags: 16.04, kiosk

I am running a chromium kiosk. in my rc.local I have

```
sudo -u myuser startx &
```

to boot my ubuntu and start it with a chromium. Since 16.04 i get the following error:

```
 parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)
```

Running startx as root in `rc.local` works.

Logging in as myuser manually then startx works too.

Comment: ran into the same problem, did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer, however you can work around that error message by adding an ACL to /dev/tty0:

```
sudo setfacl -m u:kioskme:rw /dev/tty0
```